# jqGrid filter with jquery.ui slider: strange behavior when value less than 100

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

We've implemented filtering (in a webshop) using jquery.ui components like buttons and sliders, outside of the jqGrid. The available filters for a listing (grid) depend on which category that is currently active. We create rules and add them to the filters property when buttons and sliders are pushed/used, and remove them when neccessary.

This works like a charm in most cases, but when creating a certain filter for a category containing values ranging from < 100 to > 100 something strange happens with the results if we use a slider to filter with. As soon we start pulling in the lower part of the slider the whole result set goes away when the lower value is greater than the lowest value (that is < 100) but lower than 100. In this case the lowest value is 97,6 and for values 98 and 99 on the slider the result is empty. But when the slider value become 100 or more the result is correct. I've also changed the article that has a value lower than 100 to be > 100 and then everything works as intended.

When pulling on the lower end of the slider we add a 'ge' rule to the filters and when we pull on the higher value end we add a 'le' rule.

We use jqgrid 4.3.1 and I've also tried with version 4.4.4 today, same result.

We are also using the Swedish locale, if that has anything to do with how jqGrid interprets values in the grid.

**Update (code)**:

First we get the smallest and highest values from the collection of items to be shown in the grid.

```
else if (dynamicFilters[l].Type == "slider") {
                            //Get the smallest and the biggest value that we should be able to filter on

                            //Parse the value so that there are no non-numberic characters, and also replace ',' with '.' so that it can be converted to a numeric value
                            var currentValue = property.Value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(/[,]/g, '.');
                            var index = property.Value.indexOf(".");

                            if (index >= 0) {
                                currentValue = property.Value.substring(0, index);
                            }

                            currentValue = Number(currentValue);

                            //Specific case where no value has been set
                            if (dynamicFilters[l].Values[0] == 0 && dynamicFilters[l].Values[1] == 0) {
                                dynamicFilters[l].Values[0] = currentValue;
                                dynamicFilters[l].Values[1] = currentValue;
                            } else {
                                //Else check if the value is either smaller or larger than those in the array
                                if (dynamicFilters[l].Values[0] > currentValue) {
                                    dynamicFilters[l].Values[0] = currentValue;
                                }
                                if (dynamicFilters[l].Values[1] < currentValue) {
                                    dynamicFilters[l].Values[1] = currentValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This seem to work fine, I've debugged this in Chrome devtools and the values are correct.

Then we create the actual slider in the GUI:

```
else if (filter.Type == "slider") {
            //Create the slider filters

            //Start the container for the slider filter, the second div is then used to create the slider with the jQuery UI control
            $("#dynamicFilters").append('<div class="dynamic-filter"><strong>' + filter.DisplayName + '</strong> <input type="text" id="' + filterId + '_amount" class="dynamic-filter-amount"></input><div id="' + filterId + '" class="dynamic-slider-filter" filter-property="' + filter.ParameterName + '" filter-type="' + filter.Type + '" filter-unit="' + filter.Unit + '" filter-value="' + filter.Values[0] + ';' + filter.Values[1] + '"></div></div>');

            var filters = currentProfile.Filters;
            var minValue = -1;
            var maxValue = -1;

            //Check if there are any values saved for this very filter, if so set the values of the slider
            if (filters != null && !currentProfile.FilterListUrlChanged) {
                for (var j = 0; j < filters.length; j++) {
                    if (filters[j].Field == filter.ParameterName && filters[j].OperatorType == "ge") {
                        minValue = filters[j].Data;
                    }
                    if (filters[j].Field == filter.ParameterName && filters[j].OperatorType == "le") {
                        maxValue = filters[j].Data;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                minValue = filter.Values[0];
                maxValue = filter.Values[1];
            }

            if (minValue == -1) {
                minValue = filter.Values[0];
            }

            if (maxValue == -1) {
                maxValue = filter.Values[1];
            }

            //Create the actual slider
            if (filter.Values[0] != filter.Values[1]) {
                $("#" + filterId).slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: parseInt(filter.Values[0]),
                    max: parseInt(filter.Values[1]),
                    values: [parseInt(minValue), parseInt(maxValue)],
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        var filterProperty = $(this).attr("filter-property");
                        var filterType = $(this).attr("filter-type");
                        var filterUnit = $(this).attr("filter-unit");
                        $("#" + filterProperty + "_amount").val("(" + ui.values[0] + " " + filterUnit + " - " + ui.values[1] + " " + filterUnit + ")");
                        articleListFilter._applyFilter(that, filterProperty, filterType, [ui.values[0], ui.values[1]]);
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        //Add the slider filter to the current profile, but only if they have actually moved from their initial position
                        if (ui.values[0] != $(this).slider("option", "min")) {
                            articleListFilter._addProfileFilter(document.URL, $(this).attr("filter-property"), "ge", $(this).attr("filter-type"), ui.values[0]);
                        }
                        else {
                            articleListFilter._removeProfileFilter(document.URL, $(this).attr("filter-property"), $(this).attr("filter-type"), "ge", ui.values[0]);
                        }

                        if (ui.values[1] != $(this).slider("option", "max")) {
                            articleListFilter._addProfileFilter(document.URL, $(this).attr("filter-property"), "le", $(this).attr("filter-type"), ui.values[1]);
                        }
                        else {
                            articleListFilter._removeProfileFilter(document.URL, $(this).attr("filter-property"), $(this).attr("filter-type"), "le", ui.values[1]);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#" + filterId + "_amount").val("(" + $("#" + filterId).slider("values", 0) + " " + filter.Unit + " - " + $("#" + filterId).slider("values", 1) + " " + filter.Unit + ")");
            }
        }
```

This part also works (as far as I can see), the values are set correctly and it works with all other properties that we try to filter on with a slider. Even when the ranges are < 100 to > 100.

The _applyFilter function look like this:

```
_applyFilter: function (that, property, type, value) {
    var myfilter = {};

    //Get a new fresh filter or the current one
    if (that.data("Filter") == null) {
        myfilter.filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };
        myfilter.HasPriceFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasBrandFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasSmallFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasMediumFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasLargeFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasAdditionFilter = false;
        myfilter.HasMiscFilter = false;
    } else {
        myfilter = that.data("Filter");
    }

    myfilter = articleListFilter._filterDynamic(myfilter, property, type, value);

    //Must reload here so that the paging won't get stuck on a page that has no items. Must be done before the filter is set.
    $("#articles").trigger("reloadGrid");

    that.data("Filter", myfilter);

    articleListFilter._setFilter(that, myfilter.filter, 1);
}
```

The _filterDynamic function works like this:

```
else if (type == "slider") {
        //Need to check if there already is a filter for the same property and type, if the data should be changed or pushed into the rules array
        var addMinRule = true;
        var addMaxRule = true;
        var minValue = $("#" + property).slider("option", "min");
        var maxValue = $("#" + property).slider("option", "max");

        for (var j = 0; j < myFilter.filter.rules.length; j++) {
            var rule = myFilter.filter.rules[j];

            if (rule.field == property && rule.op == "ge") {
                rule.data = value[0];
                addMinRule = false;
            }
            else if (rule.field == property && rule.op == "le") {
                rule.data = value[1];
                addMaxRule = false;
            }
        }

        if (addMinRule) {
            myFilter.filter.rules.push({ field: property, op: "ge", data: value[0] });
        }

        if (addMaxRule) {
            myFilter.filter.rules.push({ field: property, op: "le", data: value[1] });
        }

        if (value[0] == minValue || value[1] == maxValue) {
            for (var k = 0; k < myFilter.filter.rules.length; k++) {
                var removeRule = myFilter.filter.rules[k];

                if (removeRule.field == property && removeRule.op == "ge") {
                    if (value[0] == minValue) {
                        myFilter.filter.rules.splice(k, 1);
                    }
                }
                else if (removeRule.field == property && removeRule.op == "le") {
                    if (value[1] == maxValue) {
                        myFilter.filter.rules.splice(k, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help or similar stories are welcome!

Kind regards, Björn

Comment: Hi Bjorn, do you have the code for the example that you described above?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I've added some of the code that goes into creating and doing the actual filtering, hope you can read something out of it! Thanks!